# How can I remove a particular element from a string in javascript or check if it's there

Tags: javascript

I have a quick question

I have string `var str="0-12345";`

How can I actually remove the dash from the string if there is one in Javascript .. How can I check if a string has a dash , and if it has , remove the dash from it ?

Comment: please do a bit of research before asking a question, check here for an answer to similar question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060804/how-to-check-if-string-contains-character

Comment: @razzak: Java is not JavaScript ;)

Comment: my mistake i havent checked actually if the link was for java or javascript, even though it's for java the `string.indexOf("character") != -1` will work on both languages, `contains()` however wont work in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

> **you have forgot to do the homework before you asked here , any way**

```
var str="0-12345";
var is_dashed=(str.indexOf("-") !== -1);
str= str.replace('-',''); //many more ideas , it seems simple to remove all '-'
```