# Having trouble with java contains

Tags: java

How do I check if a variable is equal or not equal to a contains? I want to make it so if someone where to put in an invalid operator it would say try again.

```
String operator = "+, -, *,/, %";
double num1, num2, sum=0;    
System.out.println("First number: ");
num1 = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Second number: ");
num2 = input.nextDouble();
if (operator.contains("+")){
    sum = num1 + num2;
} else if (operator != operator.contains("+,-,*,/,%"){
```

System.out.println("Error");
}

Comment: I think he means 'operator'? Still doesn't make a lot of sence

Comment: @MaxZoom Like is there a way to check if my contains is == to my operator?

Comment: @Cmi Please [edit] your question to be more clear and detailed about what you're trying to accomplish.  In the code you're showing, the "if" statement will always execute because `operator` is always "+, -, *,/, %";

Comment: @Brian I know but how do I make it so when a user enters in like 7 as an op it gives an error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to check if string contains '+' character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060804/how-to-check-if-string-contains-character)

Comment: @Cmi the else if is not even correct statement. contains returns boolean and you are comparing it to a string

Comment: @NickDiv I am not good in java so my mistake. Would I have to make it == to a boolen either true or false?

Comment: @Cmi I would guess you are trying something like this: 
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("First number: ");
 num1 = sc.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("Select the operation");
 String operation = sc.next();
 System.out.println("Second number: ");
 num2 = sc.nextDouble();
 if (operator.contains(operation)){
     sum = num1 + num2;
     System.out.println(sum);
 }

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check what operator should be used based on the user entry, you could use `switch` statement as below

```
String operator = "";
while (operator.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println("Enter Operator: ");
  operator = input.next();
  switch (operator) {
    case "+" : result = num1 + num2; break;
    case "-" : result = num1 - num2; break;
    case "*" : result = num1 * num2; break;
    case "/" : result = num1 / num2; break;
    default  : System.out.println("Invalid operator: " + operator);
               operator = "";
  }
  System.out.println("Result is " + result);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/94zs3F)

If you only want to check if the operator is valid, you can use `List` [contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method:

```
String[] operators = { "+", "-", "*", "/" , "%" };
List<String> ops = Arrays.asList(operators);
:
System.out.println("Enter Operator: ");
String operator = input.next();
if (ops.contains(operator)) {
   // do some calculation here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MaxZoom sorry if my question was not making much sense

Comment: Do not worry about that. Gentle reminder: please accept the answer if applicable.